# Loop mistake on Pine Script

Tags: loops, for-loop, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying a calculate golden cross with for loop but the code does not work (actually even I really dunno if it is written correctly). There is 2 gold cross but it says 0. I beg you to help me I am new at coding and I gonna lose my mind.

```
indicator("Cross count", overlay = true)
v1 = input.int(8, "Short WMA", minval=1)
v2 = input.int(21, "Long WMA", minval=1)
v3 = input.int(500, "Look Back Input", minval=10, step=10)

cp = 0
var label lbl = label.new(na, na, " ", style = label.style_label_left)
wmaS= ta.wma(close, v1)
wmaL = ta.wma(close, v2)

for i = 0 to v3
 if ta.crossover(wmaS,wmaL)
  cp := cp + 1
cp

plot(wmaS, color=color.purple)
plot(wmaL, color=color.orange)
label.set_xy(lbl, bar_index, high)
label.set_text(lbl, str.tostring(cp, "Golden Cross = "))`
```

Comment: “Code does not work” how exactly? What is the problem and what is your expectation?

Answer (score 0):

This part does not make sense:

```
for i = 0 to v3
    if ta.crossover(wmaS,wmaL)
        cp := cp + 1
cp
```

You create a loop, but inside the loop, you check the same condition. So by default, you just check whether the *current* bar has a crossover 500 times in a row. If you want to iterate, you should use the `[i]` operator to check the status of the crossover in the past:

```
crossoverCond = ta.crossover(wmaS,wmaL)
for i = 0 to v3
    if crossoverCond[i]
        cp := cp + 1
    cp
```